# Intersection of lists having comparing 3 elements at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried creating two separate lists by the name of 'sample' and 'game'. These contain outcomes of 3 games, eg, (1,1,0) (0,1,0) shown as [1,1,0,0,1,0] in both of the lists. I am trying to find intersection between both the lists through my last loop which should compare 3 elements of one list with 3 elements of another list and then return the match by appending it to list 'intersection'.

Eg, sample has [1,1,0,0,1,0] and game has [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]. The intersection of both should give me [1,1,0] that is the first 3 elements of 'sample' and 3 elements from index 3 of 'game'.

However, I am facing an error of index out of range.

Also, (1,1,0) in one list might get compared with the same (1,1,0) in other list twice, if that other list has (1,1,0) 2 times, which should not happen in intersection.

```
import random

P1 = 1/2 # win 1st game
P2 = 2/3 # win game immediately after a win
P3 = 1/3 # win game immediately after a loss

A = [0,1] # 0 for losing a game and 1 for winning a game

N = 100

sample_points = []; G1=[]; G2=[]; G3=[]

for i in range(N):
    Game1 = random.choice([0,1])
    Game2 = random.choice([0,1])
    Game3 = random.choice([0,1])

    G1.append(Game1)
    G2.append(Game2)
    G3.append(Game3)

    sample_points.extend([Game1, Game2, Game3])

sample = []; game=[];intersection=[]
i = 0
# creating two separate lists
while i < len(sample_points):
    if sample_points[i] + sample_points[i+1] + sample_points[i+2] == 2:
        n1 = sample_points[i] ; n2 = sample_points[i+1] ; n3 = sample_points[i+2]
        sample.append(n1);sample.append(n2);sample.append(n3)
    if sample_points[i] == 1:
        q1 = sample_points[i] ; q2 = sample_points[i+1] ; q3 = sample_points[i+2]
        game.append(q1);game.append(q2);game.append(q3)
    i = i+3

i=0
j=0


while j < len(sample):
    for i in range(len(game)):
        for j in range(len(sample)):
            if game[i] == sample[j] and game[i+1] == sample[j+1] and game[i+2] == sample[j+2]:
                intersection.append(sample[j]);intersection.append(sample[j+1]);intersection.append(sample[j+2])
            j = j+3
        i=i+3
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you put the input & expected output clearly?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this block of code

```
while j < len(sample):
    for i in range(len(game)):
        for j in range(len(sample)):
            if game[i] == sample[j] and game[i+1] == sample[j+1] and game[i+2] == sample[j+2]:
                intersection.append(sample[j]);intersection.append(sample[j+1]);intersection.append(sample[j+2])
            j = j+3
        i=i+3
```

Notice the you let `i` and `j` to run until the very end of the vector and yet you consider indices like `i+1` and `i+2`.

I would use range to indicate the increment by 3 and also we can compare two lists rather than using multiple `and` statement. I have also tried to use `extend`. You might like to replace it with something like

```
for i in range(0, len(game)-3, 3):
    for j in range(0, len(sample)-3, 3):
        if game[i:i+3] == sample[j:j+3]:
            intersection.extend(sample[j:j+3])

print(intersection)
```

Also, you mentioned that you want to avoid duplicate, you might want to use set to check for duplicate for the two separate lists and then convert them back to a list.